# Analysis of quick-sort

Tags: java, quicksort

I made a quick-sort program can tested it over a wide range of inputs.After I got all the data,I plotted it and this is the curve I got.Is this correct?What else can I infer from the graph?
[Here is the graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDNbH.png)

Comment: Why is X scale equiproportional ?

Comment: I just kept multiplying 102400 by 2.I thought it would not make any difference.Am I wrong?

Comment: Y scale is linear, so the X scale should use step 102400 (102400, 204800,  307200 etc)

Answer (score 1):

It is `nlog(n)` time complexity. So when you draw `nlog(n)`, it is supposed to be like this graph:
[image]

So I think you are correct.

Comment: Thanks,that was relieving.One more thing,if I implement a randomized quick-sort,how different would be the graph?

Comment: Remember that you are measuring on the worst case time complexity. Theoretically, QS and RQS both have `nlog(n)` for the worst case time complexity and their graphs should be similar. But in real world, their graph should lie between the worst-case and the best-case time complexity. So it is more like Average case time complexity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average-case_complexity